# java managing memory with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I am using a tomcat servlet that concurrently stores content as it becomes available to the servlet. A single request may have 1 or several thousand pieces (components) that may need to be stored.

To handle the concurrency, I use a fixed size table of thread pointers. As a component becomes available to be stored - the storing object is assigned to a slot in the table and execution begins. As the thread completes, the slot is NULLed and another storing object assigned as needed. If all slots in the table are used, then the table is periodically checked for completed threads and the thread is replaced.

Managing memory with this model can be difficult because garbage collection never completely cleans up the memory used by the treads as they die. This can result in memory overflows or memory recovery that is too small.

Is there a way to handle GC with this type - e.g. synching becomes required followed by GC? Is there a java concurrency handler that matches this type of handling ...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get why you have to kill threads after complete handling a single request. Use fixed thread pool, apply producer/consumer pattern, and re-use threads.

Comment: "garbage collection never completely cleans up the memory used by the treads as they die." what on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

What I originally thought was a problem in GC not totally cleaning up memory was that I was only seeing minor GC collection which only did a partial cleanup. When major collection did occur it would freeze our service up to 10 minutes.

After some experimenting with different collectors, it looks like the new G1 collector under version 7, does the trick.

My thanks to those who researched this.